# Android studio con java

Tags: android-studio, android-listview

estoy creando una aplicación en la que cree un expandable listview, quiera saber como puedo desde las listas que se expandieron pasar a otra activity, y una de ellas volverla a expandir.

```
       temas.add("I Bases científicas que regulan");
       temas.add("II Farmacocinética");
       temas.add("III Vías de Administración y formas farmacéuticas");
       temas.add("IV Autónomos, receptivos, autocoides");
       temas.add("V Reacciones adversas y farmacovigilancia");
       temas.add("VI Prescripciones y uso racional");

       cosas= new HashMap<>();

       List<String> bases=new ArrayList<>();

        bases.add("Guías de Estudio");
        bases.add("Autoevaluación");
        bases.add("Galería");

        List<String> farmacocinética=new ArrayList<>();

        farmacocinética.add("Guías de Estudio");
        farmacocinética.add("Autoevaluación");
        farmacocinética.add("Galería");

        List<String> vías=new ArrayList<>();

        vías.add("Guías de Estudio");
        vías.add("Autoevaluación");
        vías.add("Galería");

        List<String> ara=new ArrayList<>();

        ara.add("Guías de Estudio");
        ara.add("Autoevaluación");
        ara.add("Galería");

        List<String> reacciones=new ArrayList<>();

        reacciones.add("Guías de Estudio");
        reacciones.add("Autoevaluación");
        reacciones.add("Galería");

        List<String> prescripciones=new ArrayList<>();

        prescripciones.add("Guías de Estudio");
        prescripciones.add("Autoevaluación");
        prescripciones.add("Galería");

        cosas.put(temas.get(0),bases);
        cosas.put(temas.get(1),farmacocinética);
        cosas.put(temas.get(2),vías);
        cosas.put(temas.get(3),ara);
        cosas.put(temas.get(4),reacciones);
        cosas.put(temas.get(5),prescripciones);
```

el apartado galería es lo que quisiera k se me re expandiera para poner imágenes y videos
y quisiera que estos apartados me llevaran a otra activity
Agradecería la ayuda

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar [ask], edita tu pregunta ya que es demasiado amplia, saludos.